# Binary search implementation in Java

Tags: java

```
if(this.passenger.validatePassengerDetails() && checkEngine()  && this.capacity <= 200) {
    if(Arrays.binarySearch(airlineClassAir, "flightClass") >=0 && (destination.equals("tx") || destination.equals("ca"))) {
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(airlineClassAir, "flightClass");
        int amount = airlineClassPriceAir[index];
        double totalAmount = amount + amount* (18/100);
```

I am trying to understand how the binary search is being implemented here? Can someone explain `if(Arrays.binarySearch(airlineClassAir, "flightless") >=0` is trying to do here?

Comment: `>=` is greater than or equal to. If it is equal to `0` so  `>= 0` is true. If you want to compare strictly greater, use `>`

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(java.lang.Object[],java.lang.Object))? It says _"If it is not sorted, the results are undefined."_, your `airlineClassAir` array is not sorted.

Comment: @RickyMo Using `>` wouldn't make sense. `binarySearch` returns the index in the array of the item searched for. Using `>` would returns false even if the item exists in the first entry of the array. This is not a `compareTo` method.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel why do you assume the array is not sorted?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Look at the edit history, the initial version used `String[] airlineClassAir = {"firstclass","businessclass","economyclass"}` which is not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

As documented on [`Arrays.binarySearch(Object[], Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.Object)) (emphasis mine):

> **Returns:**
> index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise,
> `(-(`*`insertion point`*`) - 1)`. The *insertion point* is
> defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the
> array: the index of the first element greater than the key, or
> `a.length` if all elements in the array are less than the specified
> key. **Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if
> and only if the key is found.**

In other words, you compare with `>= 0` to check if the value exists in the array. Be aware though of the requirement that the array must be sorted (an earlier version of your answer showed it wasn't sorted), otherwise the behaviour is undefined: it might find the item, or it might return a negative value even if the value exists.

To explicitly answer the question, the expression `Arrays.binarySearch(airlineClassAir, "flightless") >=0` will be `true` if `airlineClassAir` contains the string `"flightless"`, and `false` otherwise (assuming it is sorted, otherwise it might return `false` even if the value is in the array).

Personally, if your requirement is to check for existence and there are no other uses of that array, I would use a `Set<String>` and use its [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method instead, as that expresses intent more clearly.

Comment: It is not guaranteed that the array is sorted. To explain in clear language the purpose is to see if the user input value is contained in the array  private static String[] airlineClassAir = {"firstclass","businessclass","economyclass"};
    private static int[] airlineClassPriceAir = {7000, 15000, 4000};  and need to find the index to assign the airlineClassPriceAir value. What would be the simplest implementation for this scenario?

Comment: @alexjohnson Either you need to sort for applying a binary search, or you should just iterate over the array and check each item until you find the one you want or reach the end of the array. Alternatively, switch to a `List` or - better yet - a `Set` and use its `contains` method, as I already suggested in my answer.